# Confused by this chmod command

Tags: permissions, chmod

Why does the command `chmod 6754` correspond to the file permissions `rwsr-sr-`?

I understand that Read = 4, Write = 2, and Execute = 1, but what value does the `s` (setuid) permission or the dashes have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`6754` sets the world, group, user, and UID bits on a file or directore, right-to-left.  For the UID bits, they correspond to `--s--s--s` in a `ls -l` listing.  That `chmod` is setting bits as follows:

```
6  --s--s---
7  rwx
5     r-x
4        r--
```

Since, by this metric, `s` overrides `x`, when these permissions are "summed up", you get `rwsr-sr--`.

Answer (score 0):

From `info '(coreutils)Numeric Modes'`:

```
           Special mode bits:
 1000      Restricted deletion flag or sticky bit
 2000      Set group ID on execution
 4000      Set user ID on execution
```